# How can I import the source files of a JavaScript library?

Tags: javascript, npm, import, ecmascript-6

I'm using a library called [selection.js](https://github.com/Simonwep/selection). In my app I'm importing from node_modules using:

`import * as Selection from '@simonwep/selection-js'`

What I would like to do though, is edit the source of these files. I copied the contents of the source [here](https://github.com/Simonwep/selection/tree/master/src) and placed it in a folder of my app.

I then attempted:

`import * as Selection from './selection-js/selection.js'`

But this throws errors (I think due to module.exports). Do I need to change the export from selection.js to get it work? Or is more involved?

EDIT: @JaromandaX pointed out that I need to clone and build the library myself. That answers my question.

New Question: Is there a way to build this project without minification/uglification? I've tried adding `compress: false` to the [webpack.config.js](https://github.com/Simonwep/selection/blob/master/webpack.config.js) with little success.

Comment: It would be easier to tell you why it *throws errors* if you included those errors in your post. They're on the screen right in front of you, but we can't quite see them from here (must be the weather).

Comment: the fact that this library's `package.json` includes a `scripts` that includes `"build": "webpack --mode production"` and  has a long list of `"devDependencies": {` suggests you need to `build` it if you want to change it ... i.e. git clone the WHOLE library, edit what you need, then *build* the library

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX that answers my question. I wasn't sure if there was a way around that but it makes sense. I was thinking of it like it was a Vue component (copying those over is quite simple - doesn't require a build most of the time)

Comment: @JaromandaX One follow up question, is there a way you could see where I could easily build without minification/uglification? So then I could copy the built file over and edit it myself?

Comment: @KenWhite Sorry for the lack of detail, I was after a more general answer. I've updated my question

Comment: sorry, no, I haven't used that functionality in node/npm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working by changing the following:

**selection.js**

```
// module.exports = Selection; <-- module exports is read only

export default Selection; // <-- added this instead
```

**my app**

```
// import * as Selection from '@simonwep/selection-js'; // <-- from this

import Selection from './selection-js/selection'; //<-- to this
```